# jQuery mobile: Uncaught no such method 'open' for dialog widget instance

Tags: jquery-mobile

Here's my code in the `<head></head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
$(function() {
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dialog1')
        .dialog({
          position: 'center',
          modal: true,
          autoOpen: false
        })
        ;
    $('.panier')
        .unbind('click')
        .click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#dialog1').dialog('open');
        });
});

// ]]>
</script>
```

And the html code:

```
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Choisissez vos pizzas&nbsp;!</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="footer">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="panier" href="/" data-role="button" data-icon="search">Voir panier</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="dialog" id="dialog1" class="app-dialog">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>A dialog</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="content" data-role="content">
            <p>I am a dialog....!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I launch my page everything's fine until I click on the "panier" button: the error raised is:

```
Uncaught no such method 'open' for dialog widget instance
```

I really don't know why this doesn't work, because a dialog widget instance *should have* an `open()` method.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are confusing the [jquery mobile dialog](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html) with the [jquery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). A jquery mobile dialog is really another JQM page just styled to look a bit more like a dialog (overlay, rounded corners). To display a JQM you just use the `$.mobile.changePage('#yourDialog', optionalTranistion)` method. That said JQM dialogs do have a close method (I'm not sure but there may have also had an open method at some point).

So for your code,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        /*  $('#dialog1')  this is JQUI code
        .dialog({
        position: 'center',
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false
        })
        ;*/
        $('.panier')
        .unbind('click')
        .click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            //$('#dialog1').dialog('open');
            $.mobile.changePage('#dialog1');
        });
    });
```

There is also a [popup widget](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html) for JQM that is in development (and has been for a little while now).

You may also be interested in the [simple dialog](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/popup.html) plug in for JQM.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking at this working example and wondering what a .changePage was being done, makes sense now: http://jsfiddle.net/kYsVp/2/